# Use the Lagrangian function to find a point of the first octant that lies on $x^3y^2z=6\sqrt{3}$ and is closest to the coordinate origin

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

From the problem, I can see that $g(x,y,z)=x^3y^2z-6 \sqrt3$ is the subject. How do I find the $f(x,y,z)$, the function that I need to maximize or minimize?

Comment: **Note**: $x^3y^2z=6\sqrt{3} \implies z=f(x,y)=\frac{6\sqrt{3}}{x^3y^2}$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Can I declare an arbitrary function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ which would be in the same region?

Comment: Are you trying to do this via Lagrangian multipliers? If so, then $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is indeed a valid objective function. (The square root of such would also be valid, but is painful to optimize.)